# List<Interface> Execution Order

Tags: c#, .net

I've got a generic interface with a method on it that returns a int value such as in the following (simplified) code. It's important to me that these should be called in a specific order (e.g. ClassA always needs to be called before ClassB). How would I go about ensuring this ordering is always correct. Relying on the list creator is not the best way to do it?

Thanks.

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    int DoWork();
}

public class MyClassA : IMyInterface
{
    private int _myAccumulator = 100;

    public int DoWork()
    {
        _myAccumulator -= 1;

        return _myAccumulator;
    }
}

public class MyClassB : IMyInterface
{
    private int _myAccumulator = 50;

    public int DoWork()
    {
        _myAccumulator -= 1;

        return _myAccumulator;
    }
}


public class MyWorker
{
    private List<IMyInterface> _myAccumulatorClasses = new List<IMyInterface> { new MyClassA(), new MyClassB() }

    public void CallClasses()
    {
        foreach(var accumulator in myAccumulatorClasses)
        {
            var value = accumulator.DoWork();

            if(value > 0)
                break;  // Don't call next accumulator if we get a value greater than zero back.
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can add Priority property to your interface, then call in order of priority

Comment: `foreach` traverses along the index of elements. Or to be more precise according to the order that is returned in the `Enumerator<T>`. If you want to make certain they are properly ordered give them a priority property and use LinQ to call `OrderBy(x => x.SignificantProperty)`.

Comment: Not sure i understand you well, but you can check if clas is `typeof(ClassA)` or `typeof(ClassB)` and depending on this, you can create ordered list to execute `DoWork` method in `ClassA` first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add an `Order` property to your interface:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    int DoWork();
    int Order { get; }
}
```

Then, in your implementation:

```
public class MyClassA : IMyInterface
{
    private int _myAccumulator = 100;

    public int DoWork()
    {
        _myAccumulator -= 1;

        return _myAccumulator;
    }

    public int Order {get { return 1;} }
}
```

And finally, `OrderBy` when you iterate:

```
public class MyWorker
{
    private List<IMyInterface> _myAccumulatorClasses = new List<IMyInterface> { new MyClassA(), new MyClassB() }

    public void CallClasses()
    {
        foreach(var accumulator in myAccumulatorClasses.OrderBy(x=>x.Order)))
        {
            var value = accumulator.DoWork();

            if(value > 0)
                break;  // Don't call next accumulator if we get a value greater than zero back.
        }

    }
}
```

This is the *safest* way to ensure order.

However, `List<>` guarantees order on insert.
So if you insert in a particular order, they will come out in that order:

```
var list = new List<string>();
list.Add("1");
list.Add("2");
list.Add("3");
list.Add("4");

foreach (var element in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

Output:

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   4

[image]

Comment: PlusOne for not using a down-casting approach.

Answer (score 1):

Alex's answer is great, but another way to do this would be creating chained lists:

```
public interface IChainedWork
{
    int DoWork();
    IChainedWork Next { get; }
}
```

And any given `IChainedWork` implementation would be:

```
public class MyClassA : IChainedWork
{
    private int _myAccumulator = 100;

    public MyClassA(IChainedWork next = null)
    {
        Next = next;
    }

    public int DoWork()
    {
        _myAccumulator -= 1;

        return _myAccumulator;
    }

    public IChainedWork Next { get; }
}
```

And now, processing the work would look like this:

```
var current = lists.Where(l => lists.Except(new[] { l }).All(ll => ll.Next != l))
                   .FirstOrDefault(); //find the first

while (current!=null && 
       current.DoWork() <= 0)
{
    current = current.Next;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a great alternative to Alex's answer. However I didn't want to give the caller the opportunity of altering that order which I assume they could given your method of chained lists, by specifying next in the chain I'd have to remember which one to call next. Thanks though, it's an alternative to remember :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please implement CompareTo method of IComparable as below:

```
public interface IMyInterface: IComparable
{
    int DoWork();

}

public class MyClassA : IMyInterface
{
    private int _myAccumulator = 100;

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        return this.GetType().Name.CompareTo(obj.GetType().Name);
    }

    public int DoWork()
    {
        _myAccumulator -= 1;

        return _myAccumulator;
    }
}

public class MyClassB : IMyInterface
{
    private int _myAccumulator = 50;


    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        return this.GetType().Name.CompareTo(obj.GetType().Name);
    }
    public int DoWork()
    {
        _myAccumulator -= 1;

        return _myAccumulator;
    }
}


public class MyWorker
{
    private List<IMyInterface> _myAccumulatorClasses = new List<IMyInterface> { new MyClassA(), new MyClassB() };

public void CallClasses()
    {
        _myAccumulatorClasses.Sort();
        foreach (var accumulator in _myAccumulatorClasses)
        {
            var value = accumulator.DoWork();

            if (value > 0)
                break;  // Don't call next accumulator if we get a value greater than zero back.
        }

    }
}
```